# How to generate unique button with button click

Tags: java, android

I have a `floating action button` that, when clicked, an `editText` field opens up where the user can enter text. The text would then be taken via `getText().toString()` and entered into the text of a new button. I can make it so that each time the user goes through this process, a new button is created and positioned below the previously created button. The problem is, each new button is not unique. It creates a new instance of the exact same button so that every button has the exact same id. How do I generate a new, completely unique button with unique id in order to reference each button individually later on?

```
            confirmBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (!editTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        projectBtn = new Button(getActivity());
                        projectBtn.setId(R.id.projNewBtn);
                        projectBtn.setText(editTitle.getText().toString());
                        project_layout.addView(projectBtn);
                    }
                    editTitle.setText("");
                    project_layout.removeView(editTitle);
                    project_layout.removeView(linearLayout);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            });
```

Comment: How do you create the button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my own problem by simply adding two lines of code; one to initialize a button ArrayList, and one to add the button to the array each time a new button is created. I simply set the id as a variable int so that once stored in the array, I am able to reference it via the corresponding number position.